# POST method for webhooks dropbox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dropbox

I simply want to receive notifications from dropbox that a change has been made. I am currently following this tutorial:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks#tutorial

The GET method is done, verification is good.

However, when trying to mimic their implementation of POST, I am struggling because of a few things:

I have no idea what redis_url means in the def_process function of the tutorial.
I can't actually verify if anything is really being sent from dropbox.
Also any advice on how I can debug? I can't print anything from my program since it has to be ran on a site rather than an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key-value store; it's just a way to cache your data throughout your application.
For example, access token that is received after oauth callback is stored:

```
redis_client.hset('tokens', uid, access_token)
```

only to be used later in process_user:

```
token = redis_client.hget('tokens', uid)
```

(code from https://github.com/dropbox/mdwebhook/blob/master/app.py as suggested by their documentation: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks#webhooks)

The same goes for per-user delta cursors that are also stored.

However there are plenty of resources how to install Redis, for example:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

In this case your redis_url would be something like:

> "redis://localhost:6379/"

There are also hosted solutions, e.g. http://redistogo.com/

Possible workaround would be to use database for such purpose.

As for debugging, you could use logging facility for Python, it's thread safe and capable of writing output to file stream, it should provide you with plenty information if properly used.

More info here:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html